# Finding distance between consecutive points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, distance

I am wondering how I can get the distance between consecutive GPS locations in ArcMap 10 (i.e. the distance between consecutive GPS locations sent in during a wildlife telemetry study).

Comment: What unit does that python script generate the distance in?

Comment: This is not an answer - please don't use an answer to ask questions or make comments

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't able to comment above as my account is new and I didn't have the "50 reputation" necessary to comment. That being said, I am still very interested in what unit the distances are being generated in.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95580)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your points are in order, and that this works at 10.0 (I'm using 10.2):

Field Calculator Expression:

```
dist( !Shape! )
```

Field Calculator Code Block:

```
count = 0
def dist(shape):
    global prev
    global count
    point = arcpy.PointGeometry(shape.getPart(0))
    if count > 0:
        distance = point.distanceTo(prev)
    else:
        distance = 0
    prev = point
    count = count+1
    return distance
```

Parser: `Python`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is to go in the field calculator?

Comment: Yes, make sure to switch to Python parser.

Comment: It works! Perfect thank you so much I really appreciate it!

Comment: thanks for the answer this is great. What if I want to check a condition when calculating the value, such that the value of the current record in one field is different than the value of the previous record's field? Can I do this in the field calculator or do I need to use a cursor? If the values are the same I want to do the calculation, if they are different, return 0.

Comment: Sure, you would add the field to the expression (e.g. dist(!Shape!, !myField!)), create a new variable in the function definition (e.g. def dist(shape, myfield)), and then reference the new variable in an 'if' statement.

Comment: I added a screenshot to your answer in response to: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210569/calulating-distance-between-consecutive-points-using-arcgis-desktop