# Calculating distance between consecutive points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.4

I am not able to get the answer to the question below to work for me using the information provided:

[Finding distance between consecutive points using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118649/finding-distance-between-consecutive-points-using-arcgis-desktop)

Could someone post a screenshot?

I am using 10.0 but have access to 10.4.

I just tried running it in 10.0 and received the following error message:
"There was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for details."

The info. in the geoprocessing window doesn't mean anything to me.

I am heading to work and will run it again on 10.4.

Error message from 10.4:

the multi-line text you entered in the "YEAR =" edit box when switching to Advanced mod. if this is a vb/a script, you need to select, cut and past the text from this edit box to the pre-logic edit box

I couldn't figure out how to attach an image.  this site is confusing.

I must be missing something. I have tried this with different point shapefiles in both 10.0 and 10.4.  I have tried it with the field as text and numeral.  I really need to figure this out!

Comment: I added a screenshot to http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118652/115

Comment: If you have access to a non-Retired software package, I would suggest you use it.